# Array inside Array and $.map()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I try to learn [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and something i misunderstand

Why...

```
var arr = [0];
arr = $.map(arr, function(a,i) {
  return [a,i];
});
```

Return `[0, 0]`
,Why not `[[0,0]]`

but normally

```
var arr = [0];
arr = [arr,0];
```

Return `[[0], 0]`

http://jsbin.com/uhixex/1/edit

Seems like stupid qustion, But expain me pls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for the callback in jQuery 1.6+ says:

> A returned array will be flattened into the resulting array

Which basically means that if your map results in a nested array, the nesting will be discarded and a single-dimension array will be returned.